# How do I use an ActionView::Helper in a Ruby script, outside of Rails?

Tags: ruby, actionviewhelper

I am looking to use ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper from a Ruby script.
What all do I need to require etc.?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
~> irb
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > require 'action_view'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > ActionView::Base.new.number_to_currency 43
 => "$43.00"
```

Answer (score 22):

As of Rails 3.2.13, you can do the following:

```
class MyClass
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  def my_method
    ...
    number_with_precision(number, precision: 2)
    ...
  end
end
```

You might need to `require 'action_view'` too.

Edit: This answer is still valid in Rails 4.2.3.

Comment: `require 'action_view'` is what I was missing. Thank you.

Comment: This was helpful. I think you can skip require 'action_view' if you're running the script via 'rails runner'