# Localizing numbers in Ruby without Rails

Tags: ruby, localization

I've got a Ruby app that is not using Rails, but needs localization.  I've been using the [I18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n) gem, which works well for dates, times, and strings.  It doesn't seem to do numbers, though, unless I'm missing something.

I found the NumberHelper class in ActionView from Rails, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853015/how-do-i-use-an-actionviewhelper-in-a-ruby-script-outside-of-rails) says how you can include it in a non-Rails app.  However, making my app dependent on the whole activemodel framework seems like overkill just to get a few numeric localization routines.

Is there a better way to approach this?   Should I be using one of the other Ruby localization libraries instead?

Comment: Have you tried making the number a string?  As in, use the value `"8"` instead of `8`?

Comment: @drderp:  When I said localizing numbers, I meant localizing with the delimeter and separator - like in some languages 1,000.23 would be 1.000,23.

Comment: I thought that was also in I18n, weird...

Comment: @drderp: Perhaps it is, but when I do I18n.localize(1000.23) I get an error that localize only works for dates and times.   I didn't see any other method to do it - maybe I'm missing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the gem R18n for that: https://github.com/ai/r18n

It can do the same stuff as I18n but is more flexible and can also localize numbers. It does not have dependencies of other gems.

Basic usage:

- Add `r18n-core` to Gemfile
- Initialize with `R18n.extension_places << 'path/to/yml/files'

And then either:

```
i18n = R18n::I18n.new('en')
i18n.t[:foo][:bar] # => "Translated text"
i18n.l(123.45) # => "123.45"
```

Or the more static version:

```
R18n.locale = 'en'
R18n.t[:foo][:bar]
R18n.l(123.45)
```

Helpers exists (in other gems) for rails and sinatra